# Is it possible to have more than one parameters in data for a FlatList?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Like this for example:

```
<FlatList data={ this.state.foods, this.state.trees }
          renderItem={({item}) => <View><Text>{item.food}</Text><Text>{item.tree}</Text></View>
/>
```

As long as I have the same key (`id`), is it possible this can work like this?

`this.state.foods`:

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "food":"chicken",
  "cal":"1000",
}]
```

`this.state.trees`:

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "tree":"pine",
  "size":"10",
}]
```

EDIT:

```
    render(){
      const {trees, foods} = this.state
const combinedArray = trees.map(tree => Object.assign(tree, foods.find(food => food.id == tree.id)));
      return(




    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (!prevState.foods) {

        fetch('https://www.example.com/React/food.php')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             foods:  responseJson.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) }))

             }, function() {

           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           //console.error(error);
         });
         fetch('https://www.example.com/React/tree.php')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                trees:  responseJson
                }, function() {

              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              //console.error(error);
            });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a single `array` to a `Flatlist` [data](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data).

You can group the objects based on `id` and use them

```
const {trees, foods} = this.state
const combinedArray = trees.map(tree => Object.assign(tree, foods.find(food => food.id == tree.id)));
```

and then use `combinedArray` in the `Flatlist`

If your `state` is `undefined` or `null` initially then you need to add

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      trees: [],
      foods: []
    }
   }
```

to your class component.

Comment: Ok I finished implementing this to my code and  I got this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'trees.map')

Comment: Can you post the complete `func` where you used the object, and also how you initialize the state.

Comment: Also add the `initial state` definition.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? Do you mean where I fetched it and changed it to this.state?

Comment: The `initial state`, where you initialized your `state`, either in `constructor` or as a `class variable` directly

Comment: Ok I updated my question again. I initialize it in the constructor with a empty string then change the state when I fetch from the server

Comment: Okay, i've updated the answer, try adding initial values to the `state` as above

Comment: Is there a difference between using an empty string and and using empty brackets?

Comment: `.map` will only run for `arrays`, for others it will throw an error

Comment: Yeah the error goes away, but now nothing will render. Does it something to do with how I am already mapping `food`?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try logging the `state` and check if `combinedArrays ` contains values or not

Comment: Ok I checked and it turns out that there's just something wrong with that code you gave me and when I use `[]` the data does not fetch properly. It only fetches correct when I have no initial state.

Comment: I found out why it wasn't showing! I usually don't use `const` so instead I used `this.state` without initalization and it works!